# Query to find the current size of janusGraph?

Tags: graph-databases, tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

What is the Query to find the current size of janusGraph?

or is there any Tinkerpop query to find the database size?

Comment: Are you looking to count the number of vertices/edges in the Graph? If yes g.V().count()  will give the total vertices size and g.E().count() will give the count for the total edges, but if the graph size is huge these query might failed and we require OLAP related approach using Spark Integration